# Обработка полученных данных в FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, fastapi

Я хочу сделать небольшую серверную часть на Python (3.9), которая будет принимать POST запросы в формате JSON, записывать полученные данные в файл, и задействовать функцию которая запустит дальнейшую обработку файла.

Я выбрал FastAPI т.к в этом не шарю от слова совсем, читал читал, перечитался... **Ответа на свой вопрос я не нашел**, начал эксперементировать, **по документации сделал "Hello, world"** и начал копать, нашел декоратор **@app.post()**, с ним также поэксперементировал и ничего не понял.

Очень прошу показать осуществление моей задачи на примере, с комментариями. Если вы подскажете решение на любой другой библиотеке буду не против.

Comment: Что именно не нашли? В документации вроде всё есть https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) вместе с [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) то получается что-то в этом роде.

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

def my_sum():
    s = 0
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        nums = f.read().splitlines()
        for el in nums:
            s+=int(el)
    return(s)

app = FastAPI()

class Item(BaseModel):
    Index:int    

@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "word"}


@app.post("/post")
async def sum_index(item: Item):
    with  open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(item.Index):
            f.write(str(i) + '\n')
    result = my_sum()
    return result
```